# How to prevent word splitting in FPDF Multicell wrapping?

Tags: php, fpdf, word-wrap

I have this pdf divided as a grid. In each cell of the grid I want to insert a text and since I want the text to fit in the cell I used Multicell.

The problem is that I DO want the text to wrap, but I don't want it to break the words. Here is an image to show what I mean. I don't want the word "Prevent" split

[image].

Comment: Have you made an attempt at coding this for yourself?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz I had a look to the source code of fpdf.php, but the variables haven't clear names, so it's not that easy to understand how to modify it